# Ms Access Table Design - list or new table

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a table:

```
tblA
ID    = Autonumber
Price = Number
Name  = Text
```

The field [Name] contains values from a list. The list has 2-3 values.

I will add 2more values in the list, so total 5values.

What is better for performance for my database. 
The field to be list or create another table and place there the values? What is better for database size and speed?

```
New Design:

tblA                                   tblB
ID     = Autonumber                    NameID = Autonumber
Price  = Number                        Name   = Text
NameID = Number
```

Thank you.

Comment: Go for table as it easy to maintain & flexible. To speed up you can create an index on the field.

Comment: The "New design" as shown is not normalized. It would create duplicate rows for the price.  Instead, 1) eliminate `tblA.NameID`; 2) replace `tblB.NameID` field with a normal numerical Long field (not AutoNumber), perhaps named something like `tblA_ID`.  This is the foreign key to the primary table. ; 3) rename table `tblB` to `[tblNames]` (only to emphasize what it contains)

Comment: The entire purpose of a relational database like Access is to create multiple, normalized tables.  Normalization is the steps taken to eliminate redundant values and to organize data into efficient relationships.  There are too many resources and useful webpages to list them here, so I recommend searching the web for "database normalization".   Some of them may be difficult to understand, but reviewing multiple explanations and trying them in practice will help.

Comment: @Santosh Be more detail with index (mark fields (*) to index in my tables) and please write it as an answer in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookup table is better than creating a Value list.

1. A lookup table is easy to maintain whereas as Value list are kind of hardcoded and gets difficult especially when the list grows gradually.
2. You can add `sort_by` Number field in `tblB` for custom sorting the list
3. You can add `inactive` Yes/No field in `tblB` to easily turn off any value
4. New table design will reduce the database size as it avoids data redundancy.
5. Set Name as primary key in tblB which will automatically create index and help to speed up. Speed impact would be more seen in case database grows huge or poor network connection.